# deleteObject error in UITableView, can't duplicate

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, core-data

I have my first app in the App Store and am getting an error that I cannot reproduce on any of my devices.  One user reported that he cannot delete a product without the app crashing. I have tried everything I can think of to reproduce and have had no luck. There have been no crash reports in iTunes Connect, so I signed up for Crittercism. Now I know that there are three users having the problem.

The trouble is that even with the crash logs, I still can't figure out why the app is crashing.  It never crashes for me when I delete an item - even a newly created one with no user-input information. Any recommendations on what might help me narrow down the issue would be greatly appreciated.  The app uses core data and all of the delete rules for the product entity with other entities are either set to nullify or cascade.

The crash logs indicate that the reason for the crash is "NSInvalidArgumentException - deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument".  Here is the backtrace:

```
Reported    Name    Reason  App Version     Symbolicated
15-May-12 07:22:06 PM   NSInvalidArgumentException  
-deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument

0   CoreFoundation 0x317a888f __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x315f3259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreData 0x3325cf23 -[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:] + 386
3   OnShelf 0x000972e7 0x76000 + 135911
4   CoreFoundation 0x317023fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
5   UIKit 0x319f0e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
6   UIKit 0x31ab65e7 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 118
7   CoreFoundation 0x317023fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
8   UIKit 0x319f0e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
9   UIKit 0x319f0dc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
10  UIKit 0x319f0da1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
11  UIKit 0x319f0b11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 492
12  UIKit 0x319f1449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 476
13  UIKit 0x319ef92b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 318
14  UIKit 0x319ef319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380
15  UIKit 0x319d5695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
16  UIKit 0x319d4f3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
17  GraphicsServices 0x32bd822b PurpleEventCallback + 882
18  CoreFoundation 0x3177c523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
19  CoreFoundation 0x3177c4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
20  CoreFoundation 0x3177b313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
21  CoreFoundation 0x316fe4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
22  CoreFoundation 0x316fe36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23  GraphicsServices 0x32bd7439 GSEventRunModal + 136
24  UIKit 0x31a03cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
25  OnShelf 0x00077207 0x76000 + 4615
26  OnShelf 0x000771bc 0x76000 + 4540
```

The only unusual thing about the code to delete the product in the UITableView is that it first checks to see if the number in stock is zero.  If it is not, then an alert is displayed to ask the user if he really wants to delete the product.  The one user who contacted me did tell me that he had the crash whether or not the number in stock was zero, so the crash doesn't seem to be related to the alert being displayed.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
             forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Product *product = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Alert the user if the item is currently in stock
if ([product.details.quantity intValue] > 0) {
    [self showAlert];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
        toDelete = YES;
        NSLog(@"Yes delete");
    } else {
        toDelete = NO;
    }
} else {
    // Delete the managed object.
    NSManagedObjectContext *myContext = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [myContext deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error;
    if (![myContext save:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
        }        
    }
}


#pragma mark - AlertView Delegate Methods

- (void)showAlert {
    // open a alert with an OK and cancel button
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Product In Stock"
                                                   message: @"All product data will be deleted" 
                                                  delegate: nil 
                                         cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert setDelegate: self];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        if( toDelete == YES)
        {
            // Delete the managed object.
            NSManagedObjectContext *myContext = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            [myContext deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]];

            NSError *error;
            if (![myContext save:&error]) {
                // Update to handle the error appropriately.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                exit(-1);  // Fail
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the boilerplate NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods from an Apple tutorial:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject 
                                                            atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                                                            forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
                                                        newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath     {

    UITableView *aTableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(DatabaseCell *)[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
                                                            atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex 
                                                            forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

..a bit late answer, but had this error message "NSInvalidArgumentException - deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument" just recently. It happened when I deleted items in master-detail table view quickly and double-clicked the delete button. The fix for my problem is to check if indexPath is nil before calling deleteObject:

```
    if (indexPath == nil) return;
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could work.

Within `clickedButtonAtIndex` method reset the boolean value

```
if(toDelete == YES)
{
   // other code here...

   toDelete = NO;
}
```

**Some notes about your code.**

If this not fix the error, maybe try to make clear your question to highlight only key points.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to be more concise next time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are calling `-deleteObject` in two different places. So the error (`NSInvalidArgumentException  -deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument`) is likely being thrown on the second attempt to delete the object you already deleted.

Comment: The reason for the two -deleteObject calls is that one is used if the quantity is > 0 and the other is used if the quantity is not.  I broke it down this way to allow the user to stop the deletion if they made a mistake.  I'll put a more explicit check on the else statement to see if that helps.  Just wish I could duplicate the error on my devices.  That would make life so much easier.